# how can I click the spinner on a Kendo NumericTextBox in a protractor test

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, protractor

Does anyone know how I can programmatically select an element in a protractor test that has the attribute `unselectable="on"`?

I need to write a protractor test that checks whether my ng-model is being incremented correctly but I can't select the arrow to click because of this attribute.

[image]

[image]

So this doesn't work in my test:

```
 var arrow = element(by.css('k-icon k-i-arrow-n')); // this should select the up, increment arrow
 arrow.click(); // this doesn't work because nothing has been selected.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS selector would not match the element, use dots for class names:

```
element(by.css('.k-icon.k-i-arrow-n')).click();
```

You may also locate the arrow up by `title`:

```
element(by.css('span[title="Increase value"]')).click();
```

Working demo test (using [this Kendo UI demo page](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/numerictextbox/index)):

```
describe("Kendo UI numeric field", function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.get("http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/numerictextbox/index");
    });

    it("should increase numeric currency value", function () {
        var container = element.all(by.css(".k-numerictextbox")).first();
        var input = container.element(by.id("currency"));
        var arrowUp = container.element(by.css('span[title="Increase value"]'));
        var times = 5;

        input.getAttribute("value").then(function (oldValue) {
            for (var i=0; i < times; i++) {
                arrowUp.click();
            }

            expect(input.getAttribute("value")).toEqual((parseInt(oldValue) + times).toString());
        });
    });
});
```